Ubuntu OpenCL can't find Intel GPU on double GPU device
I'm trying to code an opencl C++ application on an old Ubuntu laptop. It has two GPU's which are shown when I run lspci | grep VGA:
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller (rev 09)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GK107M [GeForce GT 650M] (rev a1)

Now, I've checked whether each GPU supports OpenCL or not, turns out the NVIDIA one does not support OpenCL but the Intel one does.
When I run clinfo I get:
  Platform Name                                   rusticl
  Platform Vendor                                 Mesa/X.org
  Platform Version                                OpenCL 3.0 
  Platform Profile                                FULL_PROFILE
  Platform Extensions                             cl_khr_byte_addressable_store cl_khr_create_command_queue cl_khr_expect_assume cl_khr_extended_versioning cl_khr_icd cl_khr_il_program cl_khr_spirv_no_integer_wrap_decoration
  Platform Extensions with Version                cl_khr_byte_addressable_store                                    0x400000 (1.0.0)
                                                  cl_khr_create_command_queue                                      0x400000 (1.0.0)
                                                  cl_khr_expect_assume                                             0x400000 (1.0.0)
                                                  cl_khr_extended_versioning                                       0x400000 (1.0.0)
                                                  cl_khr_icd                                                       0x400000 (1.0.0)
                                                  cl_khr_il_program                                                0x400000 (1.0.0)
                                                  cl_khr_spirv_no_integer_wrap_decoration                          0x400000 (1.0.0)
  Platform Numeric Version                        0xc00000 (3.0.0)
  Platform Extensions function suffix             MESA
  Platform Host timer resolution                  1ns

  Platform Name                                   Clover
  Platform Vendor                                 Mesa
  Platform Version                                OpenCL 1.1 Mesa 24.0.9-0ubuntu0.2
  Platform Profile                                FULL_PROFILE
  Platform Extensions                             cl_khr_icd
  Platform Extensions function suffix             MESA

  Platform Name                                   rusticl
Number of devices                                 0

  Platform Name                                   Clover
Number of devices                                 0

NULL platform behavior
  clGetPlatformInfo(NULL, CL_PLATFORM_NAME, ...)  rusticl
  clGetDeviceIDs(NULL, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_ALL, ...)   <error: 0 devices, multiple matching platforms!>
  clCreateContext(NULL, ...) [default]            No devices found in platform
  clCreateContext(NULL, ...) [other]              <error: no devices in non-default plaforms>
  clCreateContextFromType(NULL, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_DEFAULT)  No devices found in platform
  clCreateContextFromType(NULL, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_CPU)  No devices found in platform
  clCreateContextFromType(NULL, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_GPU)  No devices found in platform
  clCreateContextFromType(NULL, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_ACCELERATOR)  No devices found in platform
  clCreateContextFromType(NULL, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_CUSTOM)  No devices found in platform
  clCreateContextFromType(NULL, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_ALL)  No devices found in platform

ICD loader properties
  ICD loader Name                                 OpenCL ICD Loader
  ICD loader Vendor                               OCL Icd free software
  ICD loader Version                              2.3.2
  ICD loader Profile                              OpenCL 3.0

When I run this C++ code I get the following error:
    err = clGetDeviceIDs(NULL, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_ALL, 1, &device_id, NULL);

    if (err != CL_SUCCESS)
        printf("Error: Failed to create a device group! %d\n", err);


This results in the following output:
2 platform(s) found

Error: Failed to create a device group! -1

Which the error code corresponds to: CL_DEVICE_NOT_FOUND
Why can it not find the device? Is it default opting in for the nvidia gpu and if so how can I swap for the intel one?

According to this https://www.techpowerup.com/gpu-specs/geforce-gt-650m.c547 your Nvidia GPU does support OpenCL. However, as it is old, up-to-date drivers will no longer support it. I think you can use driver 470 for Kepler generation GPUs like yours. I don't know how to use OpenCL on Intel GPUs. I thought Intel integrated graphics didn't support OpenCL, but I may be wrong.

FWIW I have an old build of Ubuntu 20.04 with Nvidia 470 driver so I can still use my old Tesla K20X which is also Kepler generation. That's no guarantee however, it will work for yours also.

@SimonGoater I've installed the correct drivers for 470 kepler drivers and it worked! I wasn't aware of the fact that my drivers don't support it, thanks!

@SimonGoater I ran sudo apt install nvidia-driver-470 and installed the drivers from https://www.nvidia.com/en-us/drivers/details/196213/ I'm not sure which one fixed it but after a reboot it now works.
